# Jenkinsfile pipeline run commands in loop mode in specified directory in

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

In Jenkins pipeline need to run multiple commands in a loop mode in a different directory

**preBuild = ['test\testSchemas\testSchemas', 'Common\Common']**

```
stage('PreBuild') {
   when { expression { pipelineParams.preBuild != null } }
    steps {
        script {
            pipelineParams.preBuild.each {
              dir(pipelineParams.preBuild.${it}){
                    executeShellCommand("\"${env.NUGET}\" restore -source ${env.NEXUS_SERVER_URL}/repository/nuget-group/ -PackagesDirectory \"Packages\" ${it}")
                    executeShellCommand("\"${buildTool}\" ${pipelineParams.buildCommand} ${it}")
                      }
                    }
                }
              }
            }
```

Getting error due to some syntax error, can you please help in this am new to Jeninsfile

Comment: change `dir(pipelineParams.preBuild.${it})`.  to `dir(it)` or `dir("{it}")`

Comment: @yong, thanks for your reply with dir(it) it's working thanks again for your help